# Maximum Champion Growth size

Tags: league-of-legends

I was reading about Lulu (new champion) and saw this:

> Wild Growth (Ultimate) - Lulu enlarges an ally, knocking enemies away
>   from them and granting them a large amount of bonus health. For the
>   next few seconds, that ally gains an aura that slows nearby enemies.

Then I start wondering: **what is the max size that a champion reach ? Is there a Maximum size ?**

Example: Cho'Gath's Feast + [Greater Relic](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Greater_Relic) + [Surge](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Surge) + Wild Growth + Something that make champions grow in size. Cho'Gath will grow every time ? or it will stop at some point ?

Comment: Can Zac potentially grow larger than Cho'Gath?

Answer (score 7):

Currently the largest possible Cho'Gath is with the Loch Ness skin, Greater Relic, Surge, Wild Growth, and 6 stacks of feast. You can see a video of it here:

More then likely more ways of increasing Champion size will be released in the future.

Comment: In the video description "Unfortunately, it seems that Lulu's ult doesn't actually increase the size of Cho'Gath with everything on him. Oh well, now we can see the illustrious calls that two Cho'Gaths do whilst in mating season." so it means that there is a max size ? or is just a bug ?

Comment: But by the description, it shows that even after releasing more growth skills, it will not make any champ large. is that right ?

Comment: How about Zac with the maximum health that can be built on him + all the same growth buffs ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 6 mog's Zac gets bigger than Cho'Gath.

Answer (score 4):

Wingmind has a good answer ( https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56985/22102 ) but I do have a couple of pictures from a match me and a friend did to test this idea out I figured you would appreciate.  We had only regular cho with 6x feast stacks, surge, and wild growth on summoners rift.  Had a Morgana with us in our match though :)

[image: Bigger than baron!]

[image: massive Morgana black sheild]

Answer (score 1):

In season 6 I believe zac has a larger maximum size, in fact I believe he has since elixir of iron. Due to his passive making him larger with more hp, the largest you can make him would be cinderhulk enchant on jungle item with 4 warmogs, a steraks gage and elixir of iron. Lulu's ult makes him grow more than cho gath due to the extra health. I'm not sure how big exactly, or if there's a size limit, but if you can get steraks gage off while still at full health on him, I know you'll be much bigger than baron.