# How big does Cho'gath get with Lulu's ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've seen Lulus use their ultimates and make people really big. What happens if you use Lulu's Ultimate on Cho'gath when he uses Surge or the Dominion buff while he has 6 stacks of Feast rank 3? I'll bet he could step on Baron Nashor like an oversized worm!

Comment: I thought about that just as soon as I've seen her Champion Spotlight video. Can't wait for Big Cho screenshots!

Comment: Poosible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/56983/16007

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seams that there is a cap on how much the Cho'gath can grow, there is little to non change in size with all the buffs compared to without Lulu's Ultimate, you can see a video of it here:

Comment: Awww man that's really lame